# How to add *.crt and *.key files to HttpClient in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, httpclient, x509certificate2

I have to authenticate to an external API which is protected by certificates. I got 2 files.

**Content of *.crt**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla bla bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla bla bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla bla bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bla bla bla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**Content of *.key**

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
bla bla bla
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

My goal is to authenticate on my local machine (Windows 10) and if it works build docker image and deploy it to Azure Kubernetes. I manage to authenticate with this files using Postman but I am struggling to do this with .NET 7 using HttpClient. So far I come up with such code:

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using X509Certificate2 certWithKey = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile("<cert_file_name>.crt", "<key_file_name.key>");

var pfxCert = certWithKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
using var pfxCert2 = new X509Certificate2(pfxCert);

var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (_, _, _, _) => true;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(pfxCert2);

using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://<domain>/foo"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "user-agent", "bar" },
    },
};

using var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(body);
```

but it causes exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream strea
m, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream strea
m, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.WaitForConnectionAsync(Boolean async, CancellationToken requestCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken
 cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean d
isposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
```

Could some help me with this? I already spent few hours trying diffrent solutions and nothing worked.

Comment: The error details are right there in your exception message:  _"The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted."_

Comment: Hmm, is this your issue? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/75595

Comment: Is 'https://<domain>' your server? What certificate do you have? Is it a self-signed certificate? Do you use postman to request the SAME domain with the SAME certificate?

Comment: @Dai I tried this solution from link and it didn't work.
@Dice No, `https://<domain>` is a third party api, outside by domain. Yes, it is self-signed cert. Yes i use the SAME domain and the SAME certs ;)